# Applying moving average to several time series at once

Tags: r

I have a data set containing the demand of 100 products for 52 weeks and I need to predict the demand of each product for the next period. I'd like to test several methods (e.g. moving average, ARIMA, etc.) and compare prediction accuracy. Each time series of the 100 products is stored in an mts object called Order_volume_ts. When I now run moving average with the following code, it of course gives me an error message

```
Arima(Order_volume_ts, order=c(0,0,1))
Error in stats::arima(x = x, order = order, seasonal = seasonal, include.mean = include.mean,  : 
  only implemented for univariate time series
```

I created a work-around by using a for() formula to apply the moving average to each time series and storing the forecast results in a separate data frame. Even though the code works, I feel like there must be an easier way to do this?

```
Results <- data.frame("Material_Number"="x","Forecast"=0)  #Creating a dummy data frame to store results
Results$Material_Number <- as.character(Results$Material_Number)
for(K in seq(100)) {
    MA_model <- Arima(Order_volume_ts[,K], order=c(0,0,1)) 
    MA_FC <- forecast(MA_model, h=1)   #Create forecast for next period
    Results[K,1] <- colnames(Order_volume_ts)[K]   #Store name of material in Results data frame
    Results[K,2] <- MA_FC$mean[1]   #Store forecast for next period in Results data frame
  }
```

Here is some sample data for two products (not in ts format yet):

```
    Material_A            Material_B
 1:                  0                100
 2:                  5                400
 3:                  1                  0
 4:                  2                  0
 5:                  5                800
 6:                  0                  0
 7:                  1                  0
 8:                  1                100
 9:                  2                300
10:                  9                600
11:                  1                200
12:                  5                  0
13:                  4                  0
14:                  1                  0
15:                  5                400
16:                  3                500
17:                  2                300
18:                  0                600
19:                  2                400
20:                  3                500
21:                  3                100
22:                  1                200
23:                  6                  0
24:                  1                100
25:                  5                  0
26:                  5                200
27:                  0                100
28:                  4                  0
29:                  1                200
30:                  3                  0
31:                  4                200
32:                  2                300
33:                  1                  0
34:                  2                400
35:                  1                  0
36:                  2                  0
37:                  5                500
38:                  1                100
39:                  1                700
40:                  6                  0
41:                  1                  0
42:                 14                100
43:                  0                400
44:                  1                100
45:                  4                  0
46:                  9                100
47:                  5                  0
48:                  7                200
49:                  2                400
50:                  2                  0
51:                  2                  0
52:                  0                  0
```

The ts was created with

```
Order_volume_ts <- ts(Order_volume_vector, start=c(2016,1), end=c(2016,52), frequency=52)
```

Comment: If the series are not assumed to be related (endogenously), this is the right way to go. Univariate methods do require a univariate series, you can only speed up the calculations by parallelizing. (use ``library(parallel)``, ``cl=makeCluster(4)``, ``clusterEvalQ`` and ``clusterExport`` for preparation; ``library(pbapply)`` with ``pblapply(cl = cl, ....)`` for forecasting and collecting the data). If some variables can be assumed to be related, you can check out vector autoregressions.

Comment: Thanks for this! Could you give an example on how to do parallelizing if I have a set of 1000 SKUs that need to be predicted? I understand everything up until clusterExport, but I don't understand how I can allocate 250 SKUs to each of my 4 cores/clusters and then applying moving average in parallel. All of the examples of parallelizing I find online never deal with situations where I have 1000 separate distinct items I need to work on.

Comment: There are different ways, but in my opinion it is easiest through ``lapply`` structure. I.e., when one iteration of your code can be written as an independent (to other iteration) function. For example, ``fn = function(K){ data = Order_volume_ts[,K]; data %>% Arima(., order=c(0,0,1)) %>% forecast(., h=1) -> result; return(result$mean) }``, then list-applying ``lapply(1:1000, fn(K))`` will work similarly to your ``for`` cycle, but collect the results to a list. This may be somewhat more complicated, but in essence is a more flexible approach, since you can return larger objects.

Comment: (ctd.) From here, ``pblapply`` is a wrapper on ``lapply`` with a progress bar and a capability for easy parallelization ( ``pblapply(1:1000, fn(K), cl = cl)`` ). So, in this case, you would need to ``clusterExport(cl=cl, varlist = "Order_volume_ts")`` and load the required packages through ``clusterEvalQ{cl=cl, {library(forecast);library(magrittr); ....})``. Finally, collect the results through ``do.call(cbind, lapply_result)`` or similarly. This is a rough guide, but in my opinion the simplest one, just make some corrections based on your original code.